# How to obtain an instance of Rust's new std::heap::System?

Tags: rust, allocation

I am trying to port [the allocators crate](https://github.com/rphmeier/allocators) to the latest toolchain, and it uses the now-removed `heap::alloc`. Judging by the documentation, I should be using `std::heap::System` but I don't see how to obtain an instance of it.

Comment: For personal interest, what documentation are you referring to? For instance, I don't know why you picked `System` instead of `Heap`.

Comment: @trentcl https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.20.0/std/heap/index.html It was not immediately obvious, that Heap would have default(). Looks like I should use Heap::default()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [documentation for `System`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/heap/struct.System.html):

```
pub struct System;
```

It's a structure with no fields, so you create an instance by just naming it.

```
let system_alloc = std::heap::System;
```